# copy a Worksheet to another workbook and converting to a pivot table using panda

Tags: excel, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I am copying a worksheet to another workbook using pandas,
worksheet has morethan 50 column and ~10000.
How I can convert that sheet in pivot table (as it is no manuplation of col or rows. ). I needed to
generate Pivot Chart connect to copied worksheet

```
   import pandas as pd 
   dataSw = pd.read_excel(SwReq, sheet_name="Sheet0")
    #save it to the 'NewSheet' in destfile
    with pd.ExcelWriter(DashboardXls + time_format +".xlsx") as writer:
        dataCus.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='xxx')
```

The final result I got

> ```
>    A  B C ............
> 0  1  1 1
> 1  x  2 w
> 2  v  w v
> 3  b  v x
> .  .  . .
> .  .  . .
> ```

How I can have result a worksheet as a ** table format** as below :

> ```
>  A  B C ............
>  1  1 1
>  x  2 w
>  v  w v
>  b  v x
>  .  . .
>  .  . .
> ```

Comment: `dataCus.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='xxx', index=False)`?

Comment: its removes the index , but that wouldnt give me Pivot table, output is normal worksheet.

Comment: @user3285192 but the desired output shown in your example is just the original table with the index dropped, not a pivot table.